# Matching a pattern to an input in Java

Tags: java, regex

So I came across this question in a coding challenge and am quite lost. I need to write  a function that takes in a pattern and matches that to an input. For example the pattern is `abba` and the input is `bluegreengreenblue`.
In this case the function returns true since the input matches the pattern.
The answer would have been false if the input was `bluebluegreengreen` for the same pattern.
In essence I'm trying to write a function,

```
boolean wordpattern(String pattern, string input){

     //process input to match pattern
     // return true if it matches
    //return false if it doesn't
}
```

The input doesn't have to be a meaningful word. It can be `axcdefdeefdeaxcd`
Can someone help me with an algorithm get started with the problem. I can't think of any way to get even started solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to generate a regular expression. Then apply this generated regular expression to your text.

When generating the regular expression use `(.+)` for each first occurrence of a character, afterwards reference it with `\1`, `\2`, etc.

The code could look like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class X {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        wordpattern("abba", "bluegreengreenblue");
    }

    protected static boolean wordpattern(String pattern, String input) {
        Map<Character,Integer> patternItemNumbers = new HashMap<>();
        StringBuilder regularExpression = new StringBuilder();
        int groupCount = 1;

        for (char patternItem : pattern.toCharArray()) {
            Integer group = patternItemNumbers.get(patternItem);

            // first occurrence: create new fetching group
            if (group == null) {
                regularExpression.append("(.+)");
                patternItemNumbers.put(patternItem, groupCount++);
            }

            // every next occurrence: reuse group by identifier
            else {
                regularExpression.append('\\');
                regularExpression.append(group);
            }
        }

        String regexp = regularExpression.toString();
        boolean matches = Pattern.matches(regexp, input);

        System.out.println("pattern: "+pattern);
        System.out.println("regular expression: "+regexp);
        System.out.println("matches: "+matches);

        return matches;
    }

}
```

It outputs:

```
pattern: abba
regular expression: (.+)(.+)\2\1
matches: true
```

---

Another example: `wordpattern("aaab", "bluebluebluegreen");` will output:

```
pattern: aaab
regular expression: (.+)\1\1(.+)
matches: true
```

Comment: Will this work for any patterns, like if the pattern instead of abba is aaab.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lazy matching regex with back-reference:

```
(.+?)(.+?)\2\1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rE6bR4/1)

It will match any `foobarbarfoo`.

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(.+?)   # match 1 or more any char and group it as capture group #1 (lazy)
(.+?)   # match 1 or more any char and group it as capture group #2 (lazy)
\2      # back-reference to capture group #2
\1      # back-reference to capture group #1
```

Comment: Sorry could you explain a little more, I'm not very fluent with regex

Comment: `(.+)(.+)\2\1` will do the same. But the input is `abba` - how would you transform `abba` to `(.+?)(.+?)\2\1`?

Comment: @Zeus `\x` represents match from group with index `x`. So `\1` represents match from first `(.*?)` and `\2` from second `(.*?)`.

Comment: I think `abba` was just an example. The method should probably be able to accept all kind of patterns (like `abcabc` or `abbacca`)

Comment: Yes that's right abba was just an example.

Comment: @Zeus: I've added explanation in my answer and [also check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rE6bR4/2). Btw `(.+?)(.+?)\2\1` is more efficient than `(.+)(.+)\2\1` as it involves less back-tracking.

Comment: I think @WiktorStribiżew's comment is the real key to this question.  Creating a regex for this specific example isn't really an answer to the original question.  The asker is really asking for a way to transform a pattern like `abcaabbccabcabcabc` and see if it matches `foobarbazfoofoobarbarbazbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz`